# How can I find out the center center of my cell in the code behind

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have  a xib file and it has

- Cell

  - View

    - Image View

in my code behind how can I find out after the xib file is layouted and what is the center of my cell?

Thank you.

Comment: here cell means UITableViewCell??

Comment: I mean UICollectionViewCell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Apple [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/index.html) `UICollectionViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView` so you can use `subviews` method which will return number of elements in an `array` and then divide it by 2 and extract the same from `array` by passing the `index` like that below:-

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell;//Assuming element inside cell
NSArray *vw=[cell subviews];
NSUInteger index=vw.count/2;
NSLog(@"%@",vw[index]);//it will return your element
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your image view has an IBOutlet @property declared in the .h file and connected to your XIB. You'll need a subclass to do this.

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (or cellForItemAt... if it's a UICollectionView) you can reference:

```
YourSubClass *cell = (YourSubClass *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(cell.imageView.center));
```

Comment: I tried to print out the value of cell.imageView.center in cellForItemAt(), but the values of x,y are always the same. Any idea why is that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Yes. I am using auto layout.

Comment: That'll do it. Center isn't available until you fire [view layoutIfNeeded];